# Button color in Navigation bar - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

How do you to set the tint of this yellow button to be gray? I have tried adding an image, but have had no luck.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {

        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", @"")
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                      target:self
                                      action:@selector(GoToSettings)];
        [addButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_table.png"] retain]];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without your custom image.

Comment: Is it possible to give it some color, for example gray?

Comment: addButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

Answer (score 12):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.66f blue:0.26f alpha:0.7];
```

Answer (score 5):

From iOS 5.0 and on you can use:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_main.png"]
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(GotoSettings)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, x1, x2);

 UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menu];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton;

 [button release];
 [menuButton release];
```

Comment: Working fine, but how to set title to button ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible without using image for buttons.

```
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.16f green:0.36f blue:0.46 alpha:0.8];
```

Comment: this changes the color of the navigation bar instead of the buttons.

Comment: ...but you can set the button tint this way, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220715/how-to-set-custom-uinavigationbarbutton-color

Comment: reverse it you can change the color of the button or T

Comment: may be not related, but the answer helped me. I used it in this way      toolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
and later adding the toolbar to navigation controller. In the same way you can change the color of the UIButton!!

Answer (score 0):

when you set your image of the button in navigation bar, you may want to set **UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal** for it:

```
[addButton setImage:[[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_table.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] retain]];
```

here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252194/navigation-bar-button-item-image-color-is-different-when-design-through-xib-of-x).