# How to set custom UINavigationBarButton color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to set a custom color for a button on my UINavigationBar, but only when a particular UIViewController is being displayed in it (I know this is dubious UI design, but it's a specific customer requirement).

Our current implementation uses a Swizzle to override `drawRect` for all `UINavigationBar` objects.  This is necessary so our custom navigation bar colors are applied to standard iOS screens (like when adding a new contact through standard APIs).

I want to change the tint color of the navigation bar for one particular UIViewController to be different from the others, but the Swizzle always takes precedence.

I'm testing in the iOS 4.3 Simulator.  We support iOS 3.x clients and above (iPhone, iPod and iPad), so I can't just use the newer iOS 5 APIs to customize it.

Other things I've tried, without success:

- Adding `setStyle` calls (as per [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151549/uitoolbar-tint-on-ios4/3166975#3166975)) to make the button update again.
- I tried the `UINavigationButton` hack I found [here](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/11/05/changing-colors-of-uinavigationbarbuttons/) (I know this is a private API and risks Apple rejecting the app).  I tried putting that code in `viewWillAppear` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274473/how-to-tint-uibarbuttonitem-background-color) will answer yours.  My answer, which uses a UISegmentedControl, doesn't require any private API calls.

Comment: FYI, I updated the question as I discovered the source of the problem is a Swizzle that is being done elsewhere in our code.  Using a UISegmentedControl might still be a suitable workaround so I will look at it.

Comment: You shouldn't use swizzling, if at all possible, in a shipping app.

Comment: I agree, but sadly this is existing code that I have to support :-(

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by creating a UIButton with a custom background image, as per [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5987888/112705).

In case it helps anybody, here's my code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybackground.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Login", @"Button (9 chars limit) - Login") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];
[button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 60.0, 30.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myLoginActionMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self._loginButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

In general, I think it is best to set the tint in the UIViewController like this (although in my case this doesn't work due to the `drawRect` swizzle being in place on the `UINavigationBar` in my code):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```