# Navigation bar button item image color is different when design through xib of XCODE 5

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am creating a navigation bar button using xib but when I set the image to the bar button the image color is different from the original image.

Here is my original image.

[image: Here is my orignal image]

And after adding that image on the navigation bar button item than it looks like this

[image: Aafter adding that image on navigation bar]

Comment: have you checked for tint colour and alpha of that element?

Comment: Please add some code!

Comment: @Vision i am adding bar button using xib not programetically at the time of adding in xib its showing orignal color but when running on my iPhone its color is differnt as showing in above images.

Comment: @PrabhuNatarajan when i add that button through xib there is only tint color option which is set defult suggest me if have to change

Comment: @iMove Try to add the button programmatically! http://textdump.net/read/3972/

Comment: Did you check your Attributes Inspector for the navigation bar (or Navigation Controller)? Make it ‘opaque' instead of ‘transparent’ in the ‘Top Bar’ field in ‘Simulated Metrics’.

Comment: Did you try to add it programatically or just assign an property to it and set it's alpha value there.

Comment: Your two images are not the same. Make sure you are using the correct image.

Comment: better you can try to add programmatically.

Comment: @Desdenova thanks a lot both of you. I have duplicate image one with name menu and second is menu@2x. When i deleted second one it's work for me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First, I agree with @Desdenova's comment.
The two images do not look the same, one has hard right angle edges for each line, and the other rounded.
Make sure you are using the correct image file.
If this is the case, awesome, problem solved without deviating from your `xib` implementation.  If not, just do it programmatically (as per @shankars code).
But another thing to note, I've run into problems setting custom image files to buttons, where the image gets tweaked... make sure to use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` when setting the image to the button:

**Objective-C:**

```
[button setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift:**

```
someBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "yourPictureName")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
someBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 14):

This is sample working code

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuObject:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

Answer (score 11):

Hopefully I am not too late to add an answer of my own, but within Assets.xcassets, you can click on your image and in the attributes inspector, under **Rendar As** set it to **Original Image**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Max for your answer. This is the most correct one. I changed Render As to original in my assets and it worked as expected without any line of code. Thanks one more time. This is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Because ios7 storyboard have issue i faced to fix like below.
set your tint color as image color it works

[image]

Comment: it's the best solution 'cause it does not mention write any code

Answer (score 7):

You can create navigation bar button programmatically instead of direct storyboard, this will not affect original image color

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[self backButton];

- (UIBarButtonItem *)backButton
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

   UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
   //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   UIBarButtonItem *item= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

   return item;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set tint color as well - which worked for me - 
You can generate UIBarButtonItem via code as follows:

```
#define setTurqoiseColor [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0f/255.0f green:181.0f/255.0f blue:223.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]

UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:buttonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
menuButton.tintColor = setTurqoiseColor;
```