# How to change navigation bar button color on iOS 7.1.1 / iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiappearance, tintcolor

I want to change color of bar buttons to white.

Example:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0 green:108/255.0  blue:108/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

But, when run on iOS 7.1.1, the buttons is displayed with gray, NOT WHITE. 
This problem does not occur on the simulator.

In addition, the same problem occurs UISegmentedControl.

How to use white for tintColor?

Comment: check this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340639/button-color-in-navigation-bar-iphone> may this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out it is caused by your **Settings of your iPhone**...

I once freak out by this problem too...

Check out your setting at:

`General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast -> Darken Colors`

Make sure you turn off Darken Colors.

You'll find the button turned to pure white again.

To Craig Otis:
It is iPhone's feature, some people don't like pure white, so you don't want to force them use pure white. It is a global setting for all apps. Turning it on/off depends on users themselves.
I just point out what is the trick.

Comment: -1 because while this works for his device, it isn't a good solution that will work for his users.

Comment: It is iPhone's feature, because some people don't like pure white, they prefer gray. It is a global setting for all apps, you CANNOT change it in your app. I just point out what is the trick. Turning it on or off depends on users themselves.